# File system becomes "Read-Only" on Ubuntu 11.10 using ext4

Tags: 11.10, filesystem, read-only

I have been using Ubuntu 11.01 with ETX4, I have several Desktop PC's all identical hardware right upto the SSD. The Ubuntu OS with the above spec has been cloned from a single image. I frequently experience Hardware Hangup issues, I can ssh into the systems but cannot write to the disk as I get a "read only" file system warning.
I have ran /forcefsk but after a few days the PC's start giving the same problem.

I cannot say that the Hardware or SSD's are faulty because I have another set of PC's with the same identical HW and SSD running on Arch Linux with EXT3 and they are performing seamlessly for 200+days without a system reboot.

When the system goes into a Read-Only state I get these errors in the log.

```
Oct  2 01:17:01 turret-flextouch CRON[3739]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.040068] ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen

Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.040079] ata4.00: failed command: WRITE DMA

Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.040093] ata4.00: cmd ca/00:08:00:0a:04/00:00:00:00:00/e2 tag 0 dma 4096 out
Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.040096]          res 40/00:00:00:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.040102] ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.040114] ata4.00: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:34:10 turret-flextouch kernel: [51699.360026] ata4.01: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:34:11 turret-flextouch kernel: [51700.388023] ata4.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Oct  2 01:34:16 turret-flextouch kernel: [51705.584099] ata4.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Oct  2 01:34:20 turret-flextouch kernel: [51709.056025] ata4.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
Oct  2 01:34:20 turret-flextouch kernel: [51709.056038] ata4.00: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:34:20 turret-flextouch kernel: [51709.376026] ata4.01: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:34:21 turret-flextouch kernel: [51710.404023] ata4.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Oct  2 01:34:26 turret-flextouch kernel: [51715.600030] ata4.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Oct  2 01:34:30 turret-flextouch kernel: [51719.072024] ata4.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
Oct  2 01:34:30 turret-flextouch kernel: [51719.072036] ata4.00: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:34:30 turret-flextouch kernel: [51719.392026] ata4.01: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:34:31 turret-flextouch kernel: [51720.420023] ata4.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Oct  2 01:34:36 turret-flextouch kernel: [51725.616022] ata4.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
Oct  2 01:35:05 turret-flextouch kernel: [51754.120026] ata4.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
Oct  2 01:35:05 turret-flextouch kernel: [51754.120038] ata4.00: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Oct  2 01:35:05 turret-flextouch kernel: [51754.120045] ata4.01: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Oct  2 01:35:05 turret-flextouch kernel: [51754.120053] ata4.00: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:35:05 turret-flextouch kernel: [51754.440025] ata4.01: hard resetting link
Oct  2 01:35:06 turret-flextouch kernel: [51755.468025] ata4.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting from a newer version of Ubuntu and trying to access the same drive as Ubuntu 11.04 is using an older kernel with older drivers and probably some bugs that has been fixed in the newer version that MAY be linked with the problem if it isn't the SSD itself...

Comment: Ok .. once the drive goes into a read-only state after I reboot the PC everything is back to normal, then after a few days it goes into this state again.